# How to make ropemacs faster in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, refactoring, rope

I'm using ropemacs and company-mode for code completion in emacs.

However, I oftern found ropemacs slow, for example, when I type in

```
import os
os.
```

Then ropemacs will try to do the completion for the methods under os modular, which will make the emacs stuck for 5~6 seconds.

Is there a way to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there're no good solutions. I use pysmell instead now.